# Select distinct year from date using Hibernate Criteria

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I would like to get all distinct years from a MySQL date field with the Hibernate Criteria API. This is the query that I want to translate to criteria:

```
sess.createQuery("SELECT DISTINCT year(o.date) FROM Observation");
```

I've tried :

```
Criteria crit = sess.createCriteria(Observation.class)
    .setProjection(Projections.distinct(Projections.property("year(date)")));
```

But it returns an error

> ERROR - could not resolve property: year(date) of: ca.ogsl.biodiversity.hibernate.Observation

Does any body knows if it's possible and how?

Thanks a lot!!!

Keven

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using an sql projection, so you can use any SQL expression:

```
criteria.setProjection(Projections.sqlProjection( "yeard(DATE_COLUMN_NAME) as year", new String[] {"year"}, new Type[] {StandardBasicTypes.INTEGER} ));
```

Comment: Good it works, I also want to count the number of occurences so I did replace the sqlProjection by sqlGroupProjection :

Projections.sqlGroupProjection("year(DATE_COLUMN) as y", "y", new String[]{"y"},  new Type[] {StandardBasicTypes.INTEGER}))

And it works perfectly!
Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use the `DISTINCT` keyword to query for distinct years, rather than getting all years and trying to filter them in Java code.

```
SELECT DISTINCT year(o.date) FROM Observation;
```

Comment: Oups... code cropping error... first post edited. Thanks for the warning... Now I would like to get the same result by using Criteria. Any idea?